# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration React-navigation error

Tags: react-native, gradle, react-navigation

I am having a problem with react-native-navigation packages, so I have them installed like this  `npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`. But for some reason when I run npm run android I am getting this error for every package. ```

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with
> Gradle 8.0.

> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and
> determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

> See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:comm
> and_line_warnings

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:rele
> aseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project:@react-native-community_masked-view.
> Required by:
> project :app
> No matching configuration of project :@react-native-commu
> nity_masked-view was found. The consumer was configured to find a runti
> me of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildT
> ypeAttr' with value 'release' but:
> None of the consumable configurations have attributes..```

This is my package json

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "gradle": "^1.2.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.14.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

This is gradle.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

This is settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'AwesomeProject'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

build gradle

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

     
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.awesomeproject"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Comment: Use `gradle-6.3-all.zip` run `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && yarn android`

Comment: I can't install version that is less than 6.5

Comment: Anyway it did not work

Comment: Any reason? When you update dependencies you need to make sure compatibility in the gradel version also.

Comment: I am not catching up with you, can please explain because I have installed the 6.5 version, and it is still the same

Comment: Can you add the content inside `build.gradle` & `app/build.gradle`

Comment: Ok, I have added

Comment: Try switching to `yarn add <package>` or use `npm install <package> --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different versions of react-navigation.

You can't have "react-navigation": "^4.4.4" and "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5".

So install only the 5 version or the 4 as you need.

Comment: that is not the problem

Comment: Could not be the problem, but you can't use different versions of react-navigation on the same project.